# In React.js when do inject Javascript code into JSX using `${}` and when do we use regular {}?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently working in React.js and sometimes I see people inject Javacript code into JSX using

```
`${javascript}`
```

and sometimes they use regular curly braces:

```
{javascript}
```

What is the difference and when do we use each?

Thank you!

Comment: Using `\`${javascript}\`` in place of  `{javascript}` is probably a mistake. Either you've miss interpreted where the code is placed, e.g. not directly in a JSX context, but rather just in place of a string. Or the original author explicitly wanted a string, instead of whatever the original value would have been, which likely was an edge case, or a mistake.

Comment: The 1. one is a Ecma script string templating feature. The second - {} - is JSX syntax for script injection

Comment: The first is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals and the second is https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx. They look similar, but they are very different

Answer (score 0):

`${javascript}`

In javascript, you can use expression inside string using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
`Any string with ${javascript == expression} values`
```

The react JSX uses curly brace to evaluate expression:

```
{JSX expression}
```

Where you could also use template literals:

```
{ `${expression}` }
```